# Better aproach for destructing Custom React Hooks with multiple returns?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

## Context:

I saw the documentation of react hooks and all the hooks return two values that are destructed in an array. 
But what if I have a hooks that returns an array with much more than two, like this:

`const [value, someMethod, someMethod2, someMethod3, someMethod4] = useSomeMethod(someValue)`

But I only want some of the methods, not all of then. In this case I will need to do something like:

`const [value, , , someMethod3, someMethod4] = useSomeMethod(someValue)`

And this way, it doesn't look that bad, but **imagine if you have a hook that returns more than 10**. I will show a real example so it can be more clear.

## Real example:

I'm creating a hook for dealing with arrays, so it would be something like:

```
const useArray = (initialState) => {

    const [array, setArray] = useState(initialState)

    const add = (value) => {
        let newArray = [...array, value]
        setArray(newArray)
    }

    const deleteByIndex = (index) => {
        let newArray = array.filter((x, i) => i != index)
        setArray(newArray)
    }

    const updateByIndex = (value, index) => {
        let newArray = [...array]
        newArray[index] = value
        setArray(newArray)
    }

    return [array, add, deleteByIndex, updateByIndex]
}
```

and to use this hook, it would be like:

`const [bananas, addBananas, deleteBananasByIndex, updateBananasByIndex] = useArray(someBananas)`

But if you know a little bit of array manipulation, there is much more than 3 methods, maybe more than 10.

What I want to do is create a hooks for arrays that can handle all types of manipulations for an array and use it anywhere in my project.

## The Problem:

The problem comes when I'm going to use this hooks, because all methods aren't going to be use when I call the hook, but all methods are going to be used in the project. And to use only some of the methods, it would be something like this:

`const [value, oneMethod, , , someMethod, , otherMethod, , moreMethod] = useSomeMethod(someValue)`

I thinks this is **very bad** because I need to **remember the other of the methods** and also **using alot of `,`** doesn't look good.

I thought of deconstruct it as an object, but than **the names would be fixed and also I wouldn't be able to use more that one `useArray` in a component**.

So, taking all of this in consideration...

Is there a better aproach for destructing Custom React Hooks with multiple returns than remembering the order of the returns and using alot of `,` ?

***Observations***: My question isn't about arrays, is about destructing the return of a react hook

Comment: Why not return an object, and use object destructing instead?

Comment: You can rename variable after destructuring from object like this `const { foo: bar } = { foo: 7 }`

Comment: is this maybe a better case for a [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)? you've got both actions and state to modify based on those actions

Comment: the author has made a typo `of` instead of `o` in the beginning. This question should be put on hold, marked as a duplicate, too broad and then closed.

Comment: @ZenVentzi Typo fixed, and could you explain why it should be `put on hold, marked as a duplicate, too broad and then closed`? What is the dupe question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Update

As [@worc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/769780/worc) said in the comments, `useReducer` is a better aproach and also the correct aproach, cases like this are supossed to use `useReducer`.

Also, here is how it would work:

```
function arrayReducer(array, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'push':
            return [...array, action.value]
        case 'deleteByIndex':
            let deleteByIndex = array.filter((x, i) => i != action.index)
            return deleteByIndex
        case 'updateByIndex':
            let updateByIndex = [...array]
            updateByIndex[action.index] = action.value
            return updateByIndex
        default:
            throw new Error()
    }
}

export default function useArray(initialState){
    return useReducer(arrayReducer, initialState)
}
```

Thanks for everybody that helped!

---

So the way of doing this is returning an object and renaming all of the variables

```
const useArray = (initialState) => {

    const [array, setArray] = useState(initialState)

    const add = (value) => {
        let newArray = [...array, value]
        setArray(newArray)
    }

    const deleteByIndex = (index) => {
        let newArray = array.filter((x, i) => i != index)
        setArray(newArray)
    }

    const updateByIndex = (value, index) => {
        let newArray = [...array]
        newArray[index] = value
        setArray(newArray)
    }

    return {array, add, deleteByIndex, updateByIndex}
}


const {
    array: bananas, 
    add: addBananas,
    deleteByIndex: deleteBananasByIndex, 
    updateByIndex: updateBananasByIndex
} = useArray(someBananas)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can return an object instead of an array

so,

```
 return {obj1, obj2, obj3,..}
```

and use

```
const {obj1, obj3} = useHook();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter on the returned value of function and take the desired one's only and destructure ( if you can't change your data strcture )

```
const [value, oneMethod, someMethod, otherMethod, moreMethod] = useSomeMethod(someValue).filter((_,index)=> select desired index only)
```

If you can change your structure simply use `object` and than destructure

```
const { foo: bar } = { foo: 7 , xyz: some value}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return an object instead of an array, and then use dot notation to access the required function.

```
        export function useCustomHook(data) {
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        
    
        const Notify = (data) => {
            return dispatch(openNotifyModal({ show: true, title: data.title, message: data.message }))
        }
        
        const OpenLogin = () => {
            return dispatch(openLoginModal());
        }
    
        const OpenLoader = () => {
            return dispatch(openLoaderModal());
        }
    
        const CloseLoader = () => {
            return dispatch(closeLoaderModal());
        }
    
        return {Notify, OpenLoader, CloseLoader, OpenLogin};
    
    }
    
// in your main component import useCustomHook
    let customHook = useCustomHook();
    
    const myFunc = () => {
    return customHook.Notify({title:'demo title', message:'demo message'});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think renaming is not necessary here.
So even we change to return object, we don't need to destruct and then rename.
Why not don't destruct?

```
const useArray = (initialState) => {
    bla..bla...
    return {array, add, deleteByIndex, updateByIndex}
}
```

When you use only part of it.

```
const bananas = useArray()
bananas.array
bananas.add(banana)
```

```
const apples = useArray()
apples.updateBananasByIndex()
```

The naming is super clear here.